# Hyperterminal on Win7... but where?

Tags: windows-7

The title says it all, i want to use hyperterminal like puTTY but in Win7 without using a client...

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "without using a client", but why not just use putty or puttytel?

Comment: IIRC Windows 7 doesn't include hyperterminal. Your choices are get a copy from a machine that does, or use something like putty.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know [THIS](http://digitizor.com/2009/08/29/how-to-install-the-winxp-hyperterminal-client-on-windows-vista-or-windows-7-free/) is your only option for Hyperterminal in Win7. I used this same method back when i first installed Win7. If you are hoping to get the same functionality out of HT as you do with puTTY, then you should stick with puTTY.

Comment: puTTY way better, wouldnt worry about hyperterminal

Comment: I'm also fairly sure that grabbing HyperTerm from another machine violates the license that Microsoft distributed HyperTerminal under (as it is *not* Microsoft software, it's owned by a 3rd party and licensed to Windows users). Of course, of all the possible license violations we all do every day this is fairly minor, but some people might have a problem with it.

Comment: @Mark: True. HyperTerminal was removed from Windows Vista and 7 and the only legal way to get it on Windows 7 is to purchase it.